# Error when using google maps api directions

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, directions

I get the following error trying to declare

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
```

The error in my console

```
 TypeError: Result of expression 'google.maps.DirectionsService' [undefined] is not a       constructor.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You must add script reference to the `<head>` of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used a src with the generated key. Now it works fine.